# Is there a way to mimic the trim functionality of a list with hashes? Is there a better data structure for this?

Tags: redis

I'm creating feeds for my product, much like the news feed of Facebook.

At first, I was implementing it through a list.

Every feed has at max 30 posts & and held a stack of comments. Pushing to the list and trimming the list to maintain the fact that there were only 30 posts max was easy. A nuance was adding comments, but the really big issue I had was deleting post if someone requested one be deleted. It wasn't guaranteed that a post would stay the same throughout its lifetime. This  made life very cumbersome. I still don't have a good solution for deletion with lists.

Then, I decided to use a hash instead. The hash is great in that it will keep the hash in order of when the posts entered the hash (so, it is basically sorted by time). Further, I could easily look up a post, add comments to it, delete it and be on with my day. Except, I need to be able to limit the amount of posts in the hash. Is there any way to replicate the trim method of a list to the hash? I want the oldest posts to be removed from the hash.

Maybe, I'm still not using the right data structure for this?

Answer (score 2):

A hash is NOT an ordered data structure, it will certainly not keep your keys in order. What you are looking for is probably the [sorted set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) (which is a combination of dictionary (i.e. hash) and skip list. Just use a timestamp as a score for the sorted set.

You can easily trim a sorted set by using ZREMRANGEBYRANK (by relative position) or ZREMRANGEBYSCORE (by absolute value of the timestamp).

Comment: The problem is that multiple elements could have the same score. I admit, I could now trim easier, but this makes deleting and obtaining one element cumbersome again because it isn't as simple as the hash data structure.

Comment: I need the posts ordered by when they were pushed into the data structure. I need to easily look up a post & update it with comments. I need to easily delete a post. I need to be able to have it be at max 30 posts.

Comment: are you sure a hash does not stay ordered in the order I pushed the fields into it when I call `REDIS.hgetall`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The hash object is implemented through a hash table, there is no way it can guarantee the order of the items.